# Fixing Java classpath issue with a little JAR surgery

Tags: java, jar, classloader, slf4j, dll

I just tried testing an application that uses Apache Camel 2.10.3, and immediately, upon the `DefaultCamelContext` being instantiated, got the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.<init>(DefaultPackageScanClassResolver.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.<init>(DefaultCamelContext.java:222)
```

I made sure that `slf4j-api-1.6.6` (which is what Camel 2.10.3 ships with) was on the runtime classpath. Next, I suspected that I might have other dependencies that also used SLF4J, but that relied on a different version of it. So I opened Eclipse, and ran a type search for `org.slf4j.Logger` and sure enough, I see that class listed in 2 distinct JARs: `slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar` (as expected!), and another 3rd party jar, `widget-lib-3.0.jar`.

So I opened up `widget-lib3.0.jar`, and see SLF4J packaged up inside of it like so:

```
widget-lib-3.0/
    com/
        <Widget Lib's compiled classes>
    org/
        slf4j/
            spi/
                ...
            impl/
                ...
            <A bunch of SLF4J classes, like LoggerFactory.class, etc.>
```

There's no way to tell what version of SLF4J it's using here, but I'd be willing to bet that it's a version that's earlier than 1.6.x, which is what Camel 2.10.3 wants.

So my best, slightly-educated guess is that at runtime, the JRE classloaders are finding `widget-lib-3.0.jar#org/slf4j/Logger` first, loading it, and *then* they go to load the Camel JARs and their dependencies. Then, when `DefaultPackageScanClassResolver` calls the SLF4J `trace(String,Object)` method, it's not finding the 1.6.6 version of SLF4J, rather, it's finding whatever version came with `widget-lib-3.0.jar`, and that method/overload doesn't exist.

Am I on track of way off base? If I'm off base, what does this mean to you, SO? And if I am on track, then my proposed solution would be to re-JAR `widget-lib-3.0.jar` without the `org/slf4j` packages in it (no other, more modern versions exist). My theory being that `slf4j-api-1.6.6`, which is backwards compatible, would be the only SLF4J version that gets loaded, and would then work for both JARs. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I on track of way off base?

No.  It looks like you are on-track here.

The way to confirm it would be to take the copy of `org.sfl4j.Logger` in the widget library JAR, and use `javah` to see if it has the `void trace(String, Object)` method or not.

Once you have confirmed it, there are a number of solutions:

- The cleanest solution would be to get hold of the source code for the widget library, recompile it against the version of sfl4j that you need, and build a new version of the JAR without embedding sfl4j in it.  (It is possible that you will need to modify the source of the widget library, but unlikely).
- A simpler solution might to make sure that you put the newer (and supposedly backwards compatible) slf4 API JAR ahead of the widget library JAR on the classpath.  That way, the old versions of slf4j in the widget JAR will be "shaded" by the newer ones with the extra method that Camel needs.

Answer (score 0):

> "There's no way to tell what version of SLF4J it's using here, but I'd
>   be willing to bet that it's a version that's earlier than 1.6.x, which
>   is what Camel 2.10.3 wants"...

Why not decompile the class file from the widget-lib-3.0.jar and see if the required method is there or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is the right one. SLF4J 1.x is API-compatible between versions. (Are you using Maven by the way? It's designed to prevent exactly this kind of problem).

What is `widget-lib`? Is there a version of it that doesn't include its dependencies? If there is, you should use that.